# Avoid debugging information on golang

Tags: go

I think that gc includes  debugging information by default. However, I want to avoid decompilation.

How can I remove the debugging information when compiling go code with gc?

Note:
Using gccgo doesn't solve the problem. If I don't compile with '-g' the executable is broken and only outputs:

no debug info in ELF executable errno -1
fatal error: no debug info in ELF executable

runtime stack:
no debug info in ELF executable errno -1
panic during panic"

Answer (score 17):

I recommend usage of `-ldflags="-s -w"` which removes symbol table and debugging information.

As a bonus with Go 1.13 `-trimpath` can be [used](https://golang.org/doc/go1.13#go-command) to reduce length of file paths stored in the file

Comment: What's the difference between `-s` and `-w`? Both remove the `debug_info` section as far as I can see (`readelf --debug-dump=info`).

Answer (score 12):

The go linker has a flag `-w` which disables DWARF debugging information generation. You can supply linker flags to go tool build commands as follows:

```
go build -ldflags '-w'
```

Another approach on Linux/Unix platforms is using command `strip` against the compiled binary. This seems to produce smaller binaries than the above linker option.

Comment: I forced a panic and the stack trace clearly displayed function names and line numbers using both solutions :S

Comment: Any information that the Go runtime may require still stays in the binary. This includes information required for panic messages, type information, etc. I am not aware of any way of stripping it out. This is different from pure debugging information.

Comment: Strip is not recommended by the Go Team, it may break the executable. It is better to use `go build -ldflags '-s'` to omit the symbol table, however I'm not sure if you can hide every symbol name completely.